# Get field values from manytomany relationship in Django model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get field values which is associated with another model. The model `Category` has a `manytomany` relationship with `Profile` model.

`Category`

```
id   category_name module_name
1    A             X
2    B             Y
```

`profile_category`

```
id    profile_id    category_id
1     2             1
```

For eg. I would like to display the module name `X` if category id `1` is assigned to the user id `2`

`models.py`

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=True, default="", unique=True)
    module_name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name ='profile')
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField( blank=True, null=True)
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    # Get the list of module names
```

I tried with `module_name = Coupling.objects.values('module_name')` but this is returning all the module_names not the names which are associated with user id 2

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=2)

print(user.profile.category.values('module_name'))
```

Update:

```
print(Profile.objects.filter(user=2).values('category__module_name'))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I get an error -- `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'`

Comment: Thanks Jahongir. Different error though - `NameError: name 'Profile' is not defined`.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra well, you need to `import` your model `Profile` first.